# Return Control from PyQt5 Window to Script

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 gui that is used to create an object, and I would like to implement it as a classmethod, like `<class-name>.from_gui()`. However, I can't get the gui to return control to the calling script. It seems that the gui mainloop never exits, even after closing the window. My attempted solution is:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = MainWindow()
gui.show()
print('this line is never reached')
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I return control to the calling script?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do, explain yourself better. I think maybe you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The question is "How do I return control to the calling script?". The code is my attempted solution.